# c# make elements belong to certain thread other than main thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have a c# Forms program that multithreads if an Arduino is connected.  If so, a text box will appear and right now I get an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'GyroForm' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.'

The code line that was from is this:

```
outputBox.Width = this.Width - 150;
```

This is not showing the text box, but regardless no action can be taken to modify said text box.

I have created a finction called "updateOutputBox" and it is on its own thread.  The thread is initialized here:

```
Thread outputBoxThread;
```

...

```
ThreadStart outputBoxRef = new ThreadStart(updateOutputBox);
outputBoxThread = new Thread(outputBoxRef);
outputBoxThread.Start();
```

Here is my updateOutputBox function:

```
public void updateOutputBox() {

        while (true) {

            outputBox.Width = this.Width - 150;
            outputBox.Height = this.Height - (outputBox.Location.Y + 50);
            outputBox.Location = new Point(100, connectionStatus.Height + 50);
        }
    }
```

The problem is my text box is on thread "GyroForm" (my project) and I want it to belong to thread "outputBoxThread" so that I do not get any errors regarding cross-threading.

If there is no way to do that, then how would I go about not having to do and invoke request for every operation?

Thanks!

Comment: ui can only be updated on the main thread

Comment: Use `outputBox.Invoke` to let an action run on the thread owning outputBox

Comment: You don't need a Thread. Use a Forms.Timer and/or `async`.

Comment: I have tried some solutions and when I invoke all the actions of the function in one delegate, I get an error saying that the handle is not created, but it is, so I was wondering if that means I cannot invoke when I do not need to.  If so how would I get around that???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public void updateOutputBox() {

    while (true) {
          if (outputBox.InvokeRequired)
           {
                 outputBox.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate {
                     outputBox.Width = this.Width - 150;
                     outputBox.Height = this.Height - (outputBox.Location.Y + 50);
                     outputBox.Location = new Point(100, connectionStatus.Height + 50);
                }));
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is okay, but now I have to have an else statement in case the invoke is not required with the same code...

Comment: Yes, but in the long run it will be

Comment: Remove the `if()` and always Inoke. But that `while(true)` will burn your CPU and your app. Use a Timer.